# extract contents of xml file

Tags: xml, oracle, crm

I have an xml file from crmod ( oracle crm on demand) and would like to extract the record count. (ie 17680) via a query into a table. I can extract other tags inside the xml accept the record count. Can someone point in the right direction

```
 <ListOfAllotmentUsage xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/AllotmentUsage/Data" recordcount="17680" lastpage="false">
```

Kind Regards

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@` to specify the attribute.

Using XMLTABLE,

```
SELECT *
FROM xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(DEFAULT 'urn:/crmondemand/xml/AllotmentUsage/Data'),'ListOfAllotmentUsage' 
  passing xmltype('<ListOfAllotmentUsage xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/AllotmentUsage/Data" recordcount="17680" lastpage="false"></ListOfAllotmentUsage>')
  columns 
    rec_count NUMBER path '@recordcount'
);
```

Using EXTRACTVALUE,

```
SELECT extractvalue(
  xmltype('<ListOfAllotmentUsage xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/AllotmentUsage/Data" recordcount="17680" lastpage="false"></ListOfAllotmentUsage>'),
  'ListOfAllotmentUsage/@recordcount',
  'xmlns="urn:/crmondemand/xml/AllotmentUsage/Data"'
  )
FROM dual;
```